# What are all the possible string you can use for bl_context?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

Based on the lists of inputs for [bl_space_type](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=bl_context#bpy.types.Panel.bl_space_type) and [bl_region_types](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=bl_context#bpy.types.Panel.bl_region_type) I'm assuming there is a set of special strings that you can input for bl_context correct? When I look at the doc I see

> TODO: explain the possible combinations
>   bl_context/bl_region_type/bl_space_type)

EDIT: The Todo has since been removed and the options are documented.

Comment: where in the UI or python type space is "bl_space_type" and "bl_region_types" ?

Comment: ''bl_space_type'' and ''bl_region_types'' are keys that allow you to define the context of new UI panels in the BPY.

Answer (score 4):

Op here I found the answer here at the bottom of this [Blender3D Noob to Pro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Addon_User_Interface), right after I posted this question. I guess I should of done a tiny bit more research haha.

> bl_context    "mesh_edit", "curve_edit", "surface_edit", "text_edit",
>   "armature_edit", "mball_edit", "lattice_edit", "posemode",
>   "sculpt_mode", "weightpaint", "vertexpaint", "imagepaint",
>   "particlemode", "objectmode"

Answer (score 1):

After spending a bit trying to find an updated list I had to peek into the source code to find an answer.

This link should show the currently updated list:
https://github.com/blender/blender/search?q=data_mode_strings

As of 2022 the list is:

```
[   "mesh_edit",           "curve_edit",          "surface_edit",        "text_edit",
    "armature_edit",       "mball_edit",          "lattice_edit",        "posemode",
    "sculpt_mode",         "weightpaint",         "vertexpaint",         "imagepaint",
    "particlemode",        "objectmode",          "greasepencil_paint",  "greasepencil_edit",
    "greasepencil_sculpt", "greasepencil_weight", "greasepencil_vertex"]
```